# UART interrupt in Raspberry PI with c or c++

Tags: raspbian, gpio, c, uart

[image]

I want use GSM module with raspberry pi i can send data bur for receiving data i want to use a interrupt function.pulling is valuable for me.

Comment: This is standard Linux.  Open the UART as a file (/dev/serial0) and ask for a notification when data is ready.  man poll, man select, man epoll.

Comment: dear ,do you have any simple code for this?

Comment: Google should find hundreds of examples.

Answer (score 3):

The linux UART API (really, the [POSIX termios API](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/termios.h.html), but you should use the system man pages for implementation specifics; everything is mostly in `man 3 termios`) creates a file descriptor that can be used for normal `read()`, `write()` and also `poll()` or `select()`, and therefore can be used to respond to incoming data via interrupt.

You open the descriptor normally, making sure to use `O_NOCTTY` (see `man 2 open`), and substituting the appropriate device node:

```
#include <fcntl.h>    
#include <termios.h> 

int serial_fd = open("/dev/ttyAMA0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if (
    serial fd < 0 ||
    !isatty(serial_fd)
) {
    // errno will be set
}
```

I've also used `O_NDELAY`, which is a personal preference, to open the `fd` in non-blocking mode.  The same fd is used for both reading and writing, which can be managed asychronously (or synchronously) in one thread or with greater independence in separate ones -- **it is safe to make a read concurrent to a write with the same descriptor** (I believe it is also okay to do any of these operations in parallel if you are not concerned about data ordering, but I have not played much that way).

You generally will then want to flush the OS's buffer on the port, which is 64 KiB (each, tx and rx):

```
usleep(250000);               
tcflush(serial_fd, TCIOFLUSH);
```

Anecdotely the 1/4 sec sleep between opening the descriptor and the flush seems necessary to make it effective, although whether it needs to be that long or why it seems that way I don't know -- these are snippets from some C++ classes I've been using with the Pi for a while.  Same ambiguity with regard to whether you should do the flush before or after the next part.

Namely, setting up the serial port with some UART specfics.  Those below work for 8N1, no parity, no breaks, etc.: A minimal, raw serial connection. The `VMIN` and `VTIME` are necessary for the non-blocking mode to work properly when reading (and note, this will make *reads* non-blocking regardless of how the descriptor was opened -- again, read `man 3 termios`).

```
struct termios serialSet;
memset(&serialSet, 0, sizeof(serialSet));
serialSet.c_iflag = IGNBRK;
serialSet.c_cflag = CS8 | CREAD | CLOCAL;
memset(serialSet.c_cc, _POSIX_VDISABLE, NCCS);
serialSet.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
serialSet.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
```

This isn't quite it; we also need to indicate the speed.

```
speed_t baudRate = B115200;
cfsetispeed(&serialSet, baudRate);
cfsetospeed(&serialSet, baudRate);
```

That's for 115200 baud; generally the constant is predictable that way (e.g., `B9600` for 9600 baud, `B1000000` for 1 Mbaud).  They do not have to exactly match settings in `config.txt`, but they are limited to a standard set.<sup>1</sup>  Going beyond 1 or 2 million on the Pi may be tenuous and result in lost bytes.  At or below that, with a solid connection, it is pretty reliable.

That struct is now associated with the fd:

```
if (tcsetattr(serial_fd, TCSANOW, &serialSet) == -1) {
    // errno will be set
```

And it is ready for use.  With regard to passively waiting for data, aka. interrupt polling, it is standard stuff, just like using a network socket.

```
struct pollfd src;
src.fd = serial_fd;
src.events = POLLIN;
src.revents = 0;   

int check = poll(&src, 1, -1);
```

See `man 2 poll` if you have not used that before.  This will block until data is received *or there is an error*.  Errors on individual descriptors will not be indicated by the return value of `poll()`, they are indicated in the `revents` for the descriptor (check for `POLLERR` and `POLLNVAL`).

If there's no errors and `check == 1` (in this case), you can now read data normally via the descriptor, keeping in mind it has been set up non-block.

You will probably find non-blocking reads deliver a series of small chunks -- often page size, but occasionally much less, even when a steady stream of data is coming from the other end.  Writes are buffered predictably in much larger chunks.

I've tested and timed this code using a loopback from TX to RX @ 1 Mbaud quite a bit, two threads, one file descriptor, and a **simultaneous read and write** of 8 MB takes ~10 seconds (which is what it should be -- each byte requires *10* bits).  This is without having to do anything special in `config.txt`; I just have the console disabled, and `init_uart_baud=115200`.  There is no data loss or corruption.

If you want to turn the poll into a callback you need to incorporate it into a background thread and use appropriate locking.  I use the same thread to slurp/parse messages (if it isn't doing anything else, it has plenty of time to keep up with the input buffer, which is presumably why non-blocking reads happen in small chunks), then lock the data and fire the main thread callback (or just leave it queued), rather than passing the fd between threads for polling and reading.

---

<sup>1. You can find a list in `/usr/include/asm-generic/termbits.h`.</sup>

Comment: You should use `/dev/serial0`, which is the default serial port. (The OP did not identify Pi model or OS.)

Comment: thanks dear, i am reading it carefully ant test it.....may be i want ask question again......i am considering this.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this library created by me:

https://github.com/mwheels/libcssl

It's an easy to use, event driven serial port communication library for Linux.
You can check out some code examples in the README file

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a moment to read over the ['What kind of behavior is expected of users?'](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) page of the site's help centre, particularly the section entitled 'Avoid overt self-promotion'. When you're linking to your own products it is *absolutely necessary* that you disclose that affiliation.

Comment: Copy/pasting answers against multiple questions is also [highly frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). I've downvoted this answer as, while it addresses the question, it lacks enough detail to be usable. Please demonstrate exactly how this approach would be applied here.